# Trailing hash (#) in URL breaks some Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hash

I'm having a strange issue which happens whenever a page is loaded with a hash at the end, ex. #home or #quotes. Some javascript breaks when there is a hash at the end of the link. The page works fine when there is no hash.

**Live examples:**

http://real-ufos.com/ - works

http:// real-ufos.com/#home - quite a few javascript things broken (earth's positioning, smooth scroll to hash section, comment tabs, opening prettyphoto lightbox etc)

Here is the scripts file: http:// real-ufos.com/wp-content/themes/real-ufos/js/scripts.js which I guess is most likely to contain the issue.

(Had to break up the links as I can't post more than one)

This is a similar question to [Trailing hash (#) in URL breaks some Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642323/trailing-hash-in-url-breaks-some-javascript) - but I couldn't find my answer there.

Comment: Have you looked for errors in your browser console? `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#home]`

Comment: Try putting quotes around the href value: `window.location.hash ? 'a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]'` at line 46 in your `scripts.js?ver=4.7.5` so instead of `a[href=#home]` it comes out as `a[href="#home"]`

Comment: Woh! That did the trick. Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going to your page `real-ufos.com/#home` the browser console shows an error
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#home]`

A CSS or xpath selector of this form should have quotes around the value of the attribute: `tag[attribute="value"]`

You can change your scripts.js file to put in the quotes

```
window.location.hash ? 'a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']'
// becomes
window.location.hash ? 'a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]'
//                             ^                            ^
```

This should make the syntax proper and correct the error.